# How to return a boolean value with rest?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

I want to provide a `boolean` `REST` service that only provides true/false boolean response.

But the following does not work. Why?

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class RestService {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/",
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public Boolean isValid() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Result: `HTTP 406: The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers.`

Comment: Just try to create a @XMLRootElement with just a boolean property (status or the one you prefer).

Comment: OK I see. But it would be sufficient if I return plain text true/false. I tied `MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE` but got the same 406 error.

Comment: "*not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers*" How did you try it?

Comment: Just opened the rest url in the webbrowser (firefox).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You don't have to remove `@ResponseBody`, you could have just removed the `MediaType`:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public Boolean isValid() {
    return true;
}
```

in which case it would have defaulted to `application/json`, so this would work too:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public Boolean isValid() {
    return true;
}
```

if you specify `MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE`, your response really has to be serializable to XML, which `true` cannot be.

Also, if you just want a plain `true` in the response it isn't really XML is it?

If you specifically want `text/plain`, you could do it like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public String isValid() {
    return Boolean.TRUE.toString();
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work, I get only true value, but test cases failed as it expects a response to begin with { (curly brace)

Comment: @JitendraVispute well, it does work, "get only true value" is what the original question was about. Looks like your test case is looking for a JSON Object to be returned. Different question I guess. And we might need more detail too.

Comment: It works for me without `@ResponseBody` and `MediaType`